# Center align texts in block

Tags: beamer, block

I want to center align the content in `block`, but it seems that `\centering` or `\begin{center}...\end{center}` does not work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{block}{}
         {\centering
         content that i want to center-align
         }
    \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{block}{}
         \centering
         content that i want to center-align
    \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You had a spurious `{}` group which meant that `\centering` had gone out of scope before the end of the paragraph, so the paragraph was not centred.